# Use of virtual functions in derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

In the following class, i'm aware the output will be:

Func A game

Func B game

Func A game

Func B game

and to fix it would be to make the Game functionB() virtual but I was just wondering why rpg->functionB() would call the method in the Game class as opposed to the RPG class? Can anyone help?

```
class Game  {

     public: Game() {}; 

    void functionA() {cout << "Func A game" << endl;}; 
    void functionB() {cout << "Func B game" << endl;}; 

};

class RolePlayGame: public Game { 

    public: RolePlayGame() {}; 
    void functionB(){ cout << "Func B role play" << endl; }; 

};

int main(){

    Game* g = new Game; Game* rpg = new RolePlayGame;

    g->functionA();
    g->functionB();
    rpg->functionA();
    rpg->functionB();
    delete g;
    delete rpg;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any functions declared `virtual` in your code.  Only virtual functions are resolved at runtime; non-virtual functions are resolved at compile time, according to the static type.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I had 'virtual' in front `functionA()` & `functionB()` in the game class and it worked as expected. I was just wondering why `rpg->function()` calls Game's `functionB()` as opposed to its own?

Comment: @LeeRobinson Because `rpg` is type `Game *` and as it is not a virtual function, the compiler only looks at the compile-time type of the pointer.

Comment: @LeeRobinson In the code you posted, the functions are not virtual, so they are resolved at compile time, according to the static type of the expression.  Since `rpg` has type `Game*`, the static type is `Game`.